# how to select user from span list in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, onclick

--> What I'm asking is a little difficult to explain, so please, try to have an open mind.

I'm making a phonegap app, in this app, I can register some users in local sqlite DB. I'm capable of making a list of all of them. What I want is to allow the user to clic on one user and set that user as the active user (I'd like to show it was selected somehow).

This is what I've got now (it's not capable of selecting them):

**HTML:**

```
<span style="font-weight:bold;" class="TextUser">registered users:</span>
<span id="lbUsers"></span>
```

(Now it's a spam, but it can be any other thing if it's better)

**Javasctip:**

```
function ListDBValues() {

if (!window.openDatabase) {
  alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
  return;
}

// this line clears out any content in the #lbUsers element on the
//page so that the next few lines will show updated
// content and not just keep repeating lines
$('#lbUsers').html('');

// this next section will select all the content from the User table
//and then go through it row by row
// appending the UserId  FirstName  LastName to the  #lbUsers element
//on the page
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
  transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM MyUsers;', [],
    function(transaction, result) {
     if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
       for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
         var row = result.rows.item(i);
         $('#lbUsers').append('<p class="listOfUsers"> &nbsp;&nbsp;' + row.Name + '. ' + row.Email + '&nbsp;&nbsp; </p><br /><br /><br /><br />');
        }
      }
     },errorHandler);
},errorHandler,nullHandler);

return;
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.listOfUsers {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 2%;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border:1px solid;
  border-radius:10px;
  left: 2%;
}
```

MyUsers has a BOOLEAN value (default FALSE) called ActiveUser. I want to be able to clic on listed user, and call SetActiveUserDB function (I can send via parameter or read from HTML id of selected user)

If it's easier with a button that will read selected user and then call SetActiveUserDB it'll work for me.

Thanks.

**PS:**

I'm sure I didn't explain well, so feel free to ask for details

Comment: Your explanation was sufficient I think. It's great the amount of code you supplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a click event to the `<p>` element.

```
...
$('#lbUsers').append('<p class="listOfUsers"> &nbsp;&nbsp;' + row.Name + '. ' + row.Email + '&nbsp;&nbsp; </p><br /><br /><br /><br />');

// same code as above, now we add a click event to the item you just created.
$(".listOfUsers").last().click(function() {
    // remove selected class from any selected user.
    $(".listOfUsers.selected").removeClass("selected");

    // set this item to selected.
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dJNyk/5/

Comment: Thanks @caspian, your example was great!! The best help I could ask for